# Join 2 files with conditional and loop

Tags: perl

I have a silly problem.
I have 2 files:
File A with 9 or more lines.

```
life_1,23032018,a_0300,true,21
life_1,23032018,a_0200,true,21
life_1,23032018,a_0100,true,20
life_1,23032018,c_0300,true,21
life_1,23032018,c_0200,true,21
life_1,23032018,c_0100,true,25
life_1,23032018,d_0300,true,23
life_1,23032018,d_0200,true,21
life_1,23032018,d_0100,true,24
```

File B with 800 or more lines.

```
201810021569661,23032018
201810021569678,23032018
201810021569685,23032018
201810021569708,23032018
201810021569715,23032018
201810021569722,23032018
201810021569739,23032018
201810021569746,23032018
201810021569753,23032018
201810021569760,23032018
```

I am using perl in the File A and using the 5th column to run through the number of lines of the File B and creating a third file. The keys are the second column (23032018) in both files.

```
life_1,201810021569661,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569678,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569685,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569708,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569715,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569722,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569739,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569746,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569753,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569760,a_0300,true
.
.
.
life_1,201810021569661,a_0200,true and so on.
```

But I did this the script in Perl but and it is always printing the last position of the File B and not each position of the second File.

```
$inputfile1 = "FileA";
$inputfile2 = "FileB";

open ( IN1, '<', $inputfile1) || die ( "File $inputfile1 Not Found!" );
open ( IN2, '<', $inputfile2) || die ( "File $inputfile2 Not Found!" );
my %hash;


while ( <IN2> ) {
    chomp;
    my @col1 = split ",";
    $hash{$col1[1]} = $col1[0];
}

while ( <IN1> ) {
    chomp;
    my @col2 = split ",";
    #print $col2[4] . "\n";

        if ( exists( $hash{$col2[1]} ) ) {
                for (my $i=1; $i <= $col2[4]; $i++){
                        print $col2[0] . "," . $hash{$col2[1]} . "," . $col2[2] . "," . $col2[3] . "," . $i . "\n";
                }
        }
}
```

Could someone help with this issue?

Comment: I'm thinking it would be easier to answer this if you also posted the output you want from your two small example files.

Comment: By what you show all your 'keys' are the same (`23032018`).  Then as you assign to your hash `$hash` it always overwrites value for that one key and will only have one key-value pair in the end, with the value of the last line processed.  But I suspect that this can't be (that they are all the same)?  The question is unclear, can you improve it?

Comment: @Kjetil S. life_1,201810021569661,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569678,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569685,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569708,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569715,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569722,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569739,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569746,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569753,a_0300,true
life_1,201810021569760,a_0300,true

Answer (score 1):

You have tried yourself and where close enough, so I decided to help.

First: with your `$hash{$col1[1]} = $col1[0]` you overwrite the hash value every time. You want to add it to an array connected to the key instead. A hash of arrays.

Second: it was confusing to me (and others + yourself?) when you name the files A and B, then name the file handlers IN1 and IN2, and at last the arrays `@col2` and `@col1` with numbers in the opposite order. Good naming makes code more readable.

```
open( A, '<', "FileA") or die "FileA not found!";
open( B, '<', "FileB") or die "FileB not found!";
my %hash;
while ( <B> ) {
    chomp;
    my @B = split ",";
    push @{ $hash{$B[1]} }, $B[0];
}
while ( <A> ) {
    chomp;
    my @A = split ",";
    print join( ",", $A[0], $_, @A[2,3] )."\n" for @{ $hash{$A[1]} };
}
```

Third: using field names instead of "magic numbers" for array indexes makes it even more readable.

```
my %ts;
while ( <B> ) {
    chomp;
    my($timestamp, $key) = split ",";
    push @{ $ts{$key} }, $timestamp;
}
while ( <A> ) {
    chomp;
    my($life, $key, $id, $bool, $num) = split ",";
    for my $timestamp ( @{ $ts{$key} } ) {
        last if $num-- < 1;       #escape for loop after $num prints
        print join( ",", $life, $timestamp, $id, $bool )."\n";
    }
}
```

Fourth point: This kind of joining is what databases and SQL are good at. If you have large amounts of data you work with often in different ways, look into that. Maybe try SQLite first if databases is new to you. You can also use SQL in Perl with the DBI module or with `system("sqlite3 file.sql")` for simple cases.

Comment: I quite understand your idea I have a question.
When would exist the FOR stop?
        for my $timestamp ( @{ $ts{$key} } ) {
            print join( ",", $life, $timestamp, $id, $bool )."\n";
        }
In this example: life_1,23032018,a_0300,true,21
I need to run through 21 lines the File B

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but if the key doesn't exists the `@{ $ts{$key} }` array will be empty and nothing is printed.Ok, but now I think I understand the $num variable. It's a limit to how many can be printed for each line in FileA? If so, add `--$num or last;` right under the `print` line. `--$num` will subtract `1` from $num and it will be false when $num reaches `0` and then `last` will be called and break out of the for loop even if the array has more elements.

Comment: Or add the line `last if $num-- < 1;` like in my last answer above now. This also allow for $num == 0 to print nothing.

Comment: Exactly but not FileA is the FileB. File A I need only position $life, $id, $bool. With these changes, only File A is printing.